# cdosys mail from classic ASP

Tags: email, smtp, asp-classic

I am supporting a customer running a proprietary Content Management System written in Classic ASP. Certain pages use the cdosys message routine to send email. This is used to report page errors back to me as well as email password reminders and forward customer inquiries to the client requesting site information. I utilize the IIS Virtual mail server to process the mail. If I take a text email and drop it in the inetpub/mailroot/pickup folder it grabs the mail and mails it out just fine. But mailing from the website via cdosys on asp pages (example objmail.Send) the mail never makes it to the pickup folder. Is this a possible permissions issue? The website is running in IIS 10 on Windows Server 2019.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding write permissions to the inetpub/mailroot folder and subfolders. I also added read permissions to the smtp subtrees in the metabase for IIS using Metabase explorer as a tool.